# Ghost worksheet in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook  (macro enabled template) that has a heritage back to 2003, at least. I use it for admin of golf games. I have been modifying it for changes in the handicap system and doing general clean-up.

A wrote a short utility that inspects all cells in the usedrange of each sheet printing a report of each cell that does not meet certain formatting criteria. Cells with no color should be empty and not be locked. Cells that are filled in and unlocked are required have a fill of #FF99CC....

Upon running the report I discovered that Worksheet("Birdies") **still exists** in the following sense:

- There is an entry in the Project explorer for its code module.
- The empty code module exists
- The program finds the worksheet in the Worksheets collection.
- The program finds violations of the standards and prints entries in the output file for Birdies.
- I fixed the violations from the immediate window of the debugger.
- The above fixes worked according to the rerun of the program.
  Worksheet("Birdies") **does not exist** in the following senses:
- It does not appear in the list of Worksheets along the bottom of the excel main window.
- Eleven (11) other worksheets exist in the above list.
- I cannot find it in the Format icon on the home ribbon under unhide
- It is not on the list of worksheets in the options tab of the file menu in worksheet display options drop down list. The other 11 are displayed.

I thought I deleted the Birdies sheet from this workbook in 2016 when I *created* this version from a previous version that supported different tee games.

Anybody have an idea about how to exorcise the ghost?

I haven't incorporated and code or program output because I think there is limited value and lot's of code. The current utility output is just under 30,000 lines, about halfway through the clean up process.

I am planning on deleting the worksheet from the object explorer in vba for a next step. Anyone experienced with this? I have some really bad experiences with this kind of stuff in ms-Access. Makes me leery of the possibilities.

Results of utility after cleanup and skipping ghosts, except for title line:

```
    5/29/2020 12:42:40 PM FindUnprotectedCells started
    Worksheet: Instructions Visibility: -1 Rows:  181    Columns:  11 
    Worksheet: Games        Visibility: -1 Rows:  184    Columns:  28 
    Worksheet: SignUp       Visibility: -1 Rows:  24     Columns:  23 
    Worksheet: Tee Times    Visibility: -1 Rows:  223    Columns:  18
    Worksheet: Scores       Visibility: -1 Rows:  187    Columns:  75
    Worksheet: Birdies      Visibility:  0 Rows:  59     Columns:  48
    Worksheet: Courses      Visibility: -1 Rows:  26     Columns:  26 
         Unprotected Cell: $A$2           Color = CCFFCC
         Unprotected Cell: $A$7           Color = CCFFCC
         Unprotected Cell: $Y$11          Color = FFFFFF
         Unprotected Cell: $Y$12          Color = FFFFFF
         Unprotected Cell: $Z$11          Color = FFFFFF
         Unprotected Cell: $Z$12          Color = FFFFFF
    Worksheet: Roster       Visibility:  0 Rows:  583    Columns:  6 
    Worksheet: BFlite       Visibility: -1 Rows:  127    Columns:  50 
    Worksheet: PFlite       Visibility: -1 Rows:  127    Columns:  50 
    Worksheet: LowNet-A     Visibility: -1 Rows:  187    Columns:  52 
    Worksheet: LowNet-B     Visibility: -1 Rows:  187    Columns:  52 
    Worksheet: LowNet-C     Visibility: -1 Rows:  187    Columns:  52
```

Comment: I tried to delete using project explorer - option was not present when right clicking. I also tried to delete using the immediate window of the ide. 
           worksheets("Birdies").delete
results:  Run-time error '1004' Delete method of Worksheet class failed

Comment: You can't delete (or create, for that matter) worksheets from the VBE - worksheets are Excel-land, as far as the VBE is concerned they are *document modules* extending classes supplied by the host application. Is the sheet visibility set to `Hidden` or `VeryHidden` by any chance?

Comment: In the VB Editor's Properties window, set the worksheet's `Visible` property to `xlSheetVisible` and it will behave like all other worksheets do.

Comment: There are actually two Ghosts. I tried to make them visible by setting the worksheet property and got a run-time error 1004.

Comment: The sheets were just Hidden not VeryHidden. I am thinking that they were connected at one-time and the connection is broken. I could not remove the connection either.

Comment: I cleaned up all of the visible sheets and ignored the two ghosts so the output is possible to share now. I just have to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I just added the output of my utility - took a while due to network hassles and my learning how to embed in questions. Note the two Worksheets Named Birdies and Rosters have visibility 0 - means hidden

Comment: Take a copy of workbook , write a vba code, set `i=1` and loop into all sheets to rename each sheet to `SheetName & i` if the SheetName was `Birdies` it will be the name like `Birdies11` and `Birdies12`. this may be help to solve.

Comment: set `i=i+1` each time in loop.sorry I can't edit my answer.